# fosrestbundle y jmsserializerbundle me devuelven un json muy largo

Tags: symfony3

Hola estoy usando symfony 3.3.15 para craer un proyecto que incluye una API, y estoy usando fosrestbundle y jmsserializerbundle en la cual tengo dos entidades una anuncio y otra categoria relacionadas uno a muchos y cuando hago una consulta a la api por los anuncios me devuelve los anuncios y un arreglo con todos los datos de la categoria y solo necesito su id y alreves igual cuando pido me devuelva las categorias me devuelve un json con las categorias y en un subarreglo todos los anuncios que perteneces a la categoria e igualmente solo necesito su id aqui les envio un ejemplo

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "titulo": "Venta de monitor",
        "descripccion": "ssasas",
        "precio": 80,
        "nombre": "JJJJJ",
        "telefono": "XXXXXXX",
        "auto": false,
        "categoria": {
            "id": 3,
            "nombre": "Computadoras",
            "slug": "computadoras",
            "anuncios": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "titulo": "Vendo SmarTV",
                    "descripccion": "wefwef",
                    "precio": 120,
                    "nombre": "JJJJ",
                    "telefono": "XXXXXXX",
                    "auto": false,
                    "slug": "vendo-smartv",
                    "created": "2018-01-22T23:48:37+0100",
                    "updated": "2018-01-22T23:48:37+0100",
                    "image_name": "132124646_1GG.jpg",
                    "image1_name": "132124646_3GG.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },
        "slug": "xxxxx",
        "created": "2018-01-22T21:26:55+0100",
        "updated": "2018-01-22T21:40:43+0100",
        "image_name": "25UM58_7_170914.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "titulo": "Vendo Casa",
        "descripccion": "Casa frente al mar",
        "precio": 15000,
        "nombre": "JJJJJ",
        "telefono": "XXXXXXX",
        "auto": false,
        "categoria": {
            "id": 1,
            "nombre": "Vivienda",
            "slug": "vivienda",
            "anuncios": []
        },
        "slug": "vendo-casa",
        "created": "2018-01-22T21:40:28+0100",
        "updated": "2018-01-22T21:40:28+0100"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "titulo": "Vendo SmarTV",
        "descripccion": "wefwef",
        "precio": 120,
        "nombre": "JJJJJ",
        "telefono": "XXXXXX",
        "auto": false,
        "categoria": {
            "id": 3,
            "nombre": "Computadoras",
            "slug": "computadoras",
            "anuncios": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "titulo": "Venta de monitor",
                    "descripccion": "ssasas",
                    "precio": 80,
                    "nombre": "JJJJJ",
                    "telefono": "XXXXXX",
                    "auto": false,
                    "slug": "xxxxx",
                    "created": "2018-01-22T21:26:55+0100",
                    "updated": "2018-01-22T21:40:43+0100",
                    "image_name": "25UM58_7_170914.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },
        "slug": "vendo-smartv",
        "created": "2018-01-22T23:48:37+0100",
        "updated": "2018-01-22T23:48:37+0100",
        "image_name": "132124646_1GG.jpg",
        "image1_name": "132124646_3GG.jpg"
    }
]
```

como puedo resolver esto

Saludos

Comment: y cual es el problema? si la API devuelve eso, pus eso es lo que devuelve. Quédate con lo que necesitas, o habla con quien ha hecho la API para que te de solo lo que quieres.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder es que esa API va a trabajar sobre redes lentas en verdad y me imagine que mientras mas pequeño el JSON mejor